# How can I force the game to save my progress?

Tags: need-for-speed-payback

A couple of days ago, I was playing on PS4 and the power went out. I lost 8 hours of progress.

How can I make the game save my progress safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game will automatically save when you [enter or exit a garage](https://www.reddit.com/r/needforspeed/comments/atnwpl/saving_and_auto_saving_payback/). To be safe regularly enter or exit a garage to prevent lost progress like this incident. I believe the game also automatically saves when you complete events.

Open-world activities like collecting markers, performing stunt jumps, or challenging races to one-on-ones do not trigger the autosave. If you spent a long time retrieving collectibles or performing other activities it is possible to lose your progress, as you did, if the game shuts down suddenly.

Comment: The thing is that I played a couple of races and went to freeroam online, and the game was still not saved when the game crashed.

Comment: That sounds like you experienced a glitch. Make sure your game is up to date and you are connected to the internet. If both of those are done and you’re still not saving successfully you may have to uninstall and reinstall the game

Comment: I tried, and the solution by EA Support to restore my progress was to factory reset my PS4 so that is already gone

Comment: Yup, that’s about the quality of support I’d expect EA to provide. Sorry.